# Show/Hide Parameter Values based on Selected Value of another Parameter. Possible?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to find out whether it is possible to engineer a SSRS report where the array of selectable values for a Parameter changes depending on the selected value(s) of another parameter.

Let's say I have the following two parameters :

```
House : (multi-select parameter with the below selectable values)
[x] Auckland
[ ] Christchurch

Furniture : (multiselect also, with a list of furniture within those houses)
[ ] AKL-TABLE
[ ] AKL-CHAIR
```

I want to know how to achieve showing/hiding values that belong to a collection tied to each house, in a SSRS report.

If it is not impossible, what extra tables will I need to enable this? If it is impossible within the frame of SSRS, I will give up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known as cascading parmeters.

The DataSet for the Furniture dropdown should refer to the House dropdown to filter it. So when House changes, the selection in Furniture changes (this includes initial load too)

Some tutorials:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169%28SQL.100%29.aspx)
- With [pictures](http://blog.infotoad.com/post/2009/06/25/Working-with-Cascading-Parameters-in-Reporting-Services.aspx)
- [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reporting%20service%20parameter%20cascading)

Comment: I found the MSDN page, but the other stuff is useful, thanks :)